# Can I develop Homemade redscale film at the high street shop?

Tags: film, developing, 35mm, diy

Normally I develop C41 at the high street shop (i.e SnappySnap, Max, Boots).
If I've made a reversed 35mm film (redscale) can I send it as normal for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'homemade' you mean you have turned the film over so the emulsion is on the 'wrong' side, then yes, I'm sure you can.  You might want to turn it back over so it is the right way round before sending it off.

Comment: do I need to turn it back because automatic machines that a big studio will use to develop?

Comment: I don't know whether it is *necessary* to do so, but it is *safer* to do so!  For instance when I hand-process B/W film I am much more careful with the emulsion side than the back of the film, so it helps a lot that I know which side that is.  The automatic process may also rely on that: I just don't know enough about how the machines work.